# How to connect the 0 ohm high or low

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, resistors, signal, ground

I am trying to see how I can try the different combinations to change EN1 and EN2.

By soldering the 0 ohm and turning on the device, would I get a high signal to the pin? If I desolder the resistor, would the signal drive down to low to pin?

So, with resistor pin is high and without resistor pin is low.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to give myself the option to try these three modes out but using a pull up with a 0 ohm. If I don't have the resistor soldered, will the signal be low?

Comment: A 0 ohm resistor will short out the supply

Comment: Where's the link to the device datasheet? [Edit] it into the question - don't bury it in the comments.

Answer (score 6):

You need two resistors on each pin that needs to be configurable.

One resistor to the positive supply and one to ground.

Populate one or the other but not both with zero Ohm resistors. If you populate both you will short circuit the power supply.

You could also populate the pull-up resistor permanently with a relatively high value, e.g. 10kohms, then populate the pull-down with a zero-ohm resistor to set a logic zero. This approach would have a slightly higher power consumption which may or may not be significant. This approach is often used if a shorting jumper is used (as on disk drives for example) rather than soldering a component - only a two-pin jumper is needed; Leave out for high, insert for a low.

Often in designs intended to be automatically tested a small value other than zero ohms will be used, e.g. 220 ohms. This will work just as well to set the logic value in normal use but allows the test equipment to overdrive the selected logic value for testing.

Comment: Thank you Kevin that cleared things up a lot. Does this now look correct? I uploaded a new screenshot.

Comment: Typically you would clearly label one set "DNP" or "DNI" or give it a non-zero value; the topology of what you have now is workable, but if built with both resistors actually installed (vs the "do not install" notation) it would again be a dead short.

Comment: Thank you Chris and I totally understand what you mean. Having one resistor from V+ to pin with 0 ohm will always send high and if you want low then you do gnd to pin. Would you say that is appropriate? Thanks for the feedback. Help is always appreciated.